# .ajax within if statement only firing intermittently jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

Okay, so I've inherited a mess of code I need to upgrade from a very old version of prototype to jquery 3.2.1 embedded in a very old website that uses php and smarty templates (ugh).

A user who is logged in can generate up to five case numbers; they are stored in the session variables and in the database.  these are throwaway numbers -- if they aren't used, they are eventually recycled.  While a user is logged in, they can only generate a maximum of 5 numbers.

I've translated the old prototype code to the jquery equivalent, and it is only firing intermittently.  The function call to retrieve a new case number is bound to a button that is loaded in the document.ready part of the script.

edit:  including the whole shebang

```
        function GetNewCaseNumber() {
            if (CurrentNumber <= 5) {
                if (CurrentNumber == 1) {
                    NewNumber = true;
                    $('#getnumber').val("Get Additional Case Number");
                } else {
                    NewNumber = confirm("Are you sure you want another Case Number?");
                }
                console.log("CurrentNumber: %s, NewNumber: ", CurrentNumber, NewNumber);
                // Show Confirm Dialog
                if (NewNumber == true) {
                    // Get another case number
                    // this fires sometimes, sometimes doesn't.  why?
                    console.log("Div tag to update= %s", "CaseNumber" + CurrentNumber);
                    console.log("Current html content value= %s",$('#CaseNumber' + CurrentNumber).html());
                    if (($.trim($('#CaseNumber' + CurrentNumber).html()) == '') || ($('#CaseNumber' + CurrentNumber).val() == null))                        {
                        $.ajax({
                            url: ("../ajax.php?event=ObtainCaseNumber&number=" + CurrentNumber),
                            async: true,
                            type: "GET",
                            dataType: "json",
                            success: function (server_response) {
                                console.log("Current Case Number %s", server_response);
                                $('#CaseNumber' + CurrentNumber).text(server_response);
                                $('#CaseNumber' + CurrentNumber).fadeIn("slow");
                                CurrentNumber++;
                            },
                            error: function (server_response) {
                                alert("There has been an ajax error: " + server_response);
                            }
                        });
                        $('#CaseNumber' + CurrentNumber).fadeIn("slow");
                        /* there are at least 2 casenumbers, show "these numbers" */
                        $('#thisnumber').html("these numbers");
                    }
                }
                // Hide Additional Buttons if this is the last one
                if (CurrentNumber >= 6) {
                    $("#getnumber").fadeOut("slow");
                }
            } else {
                alert("You cannot generate anymore Case Number's at this time.");
                $("#getnumber").fadeOut("slow");
            }
        }
```

I've edited that function to move where the CurrentNumber was incrementing.  It now appears to work perfectly.  Thank you everyone for your swift help and replies!

```
        function CheckCurrentCaseNumbers()
        {
        // Check what case numbers we already have
            $(".caseList").each(function() {
            if ($('#CaseNumber' + CurrentNumber).html() != "")
            {
                console.log("CCCN CurrentCaseNumber: %s", 'CaseNumber' + CurrentNumber);
                $('#CaseNumber' + CurrentNumber).fadeIn("slow");
                CurrentNumber++;
                console.log("CCCN CurrentNumber: %s", CurrentNumber);
            }
            });
            /* If there's at least 2 casenumbers, show "these numbers" */
            if ($("#CaseNumber2").html != "")
            {
                $("#thisnumber").html("these numbers");
            }
            if ($("#CaseNumber1").html())
            {
                $("#getnumber").val("Get Additional Case Number");
            }
            $("#Loading").fadeOut("3000");
        }
```

this is fired by an on click event on a button binded in the document.ready tag, and NewNumber==true is an alert confirm.  It's supposed to be updating these divs:

```
                <div id="CaseNumber1" class="caseList" style="display:none;">{$casenumbers.1}</div>
                <div id="CaseNumber2" class="caseList" style="display:none;">{$casenumbers.2}</div>
                <div id="CaseNumber3" class="caseList" style="display:none;">{$casenumbers.3}</div>
                <div id="CaseNumber4" class="caseList" style="display:none;">{$casenumbers.4}</div>
                <div id="CaseNumber5" class="caseList" style="display:none;">{$casenumbers.5}</div>
```

New console log:

Init...

```
CurrentNumber: 1
(index):23 generating case number
(index):24 Current Number: 1
(index):132 CurrentNumber: 1, NewNumber:  true
(index):137 Div tag to update= CaseNumber1
(index):138 Current html content value= 
(index):146 Current Case Number 11481593
(index):23 generating case number
(index):24 Current Number: 2
(index):132 CurrentNumber: 2, NewNumber:  true
(index):137 Div tag to update= CaseNumber2
(index):138 Current html content value= 
(index):146 Current Case Number 11481594
(index):23 generating case number
(index):24 Current Number: 3
(index):132 CurrentNumber: 3, NewNumber:  true
(index):137 Div tag to update= CaseNumber3
(index):138 Current html content value= 
(index):146 Current Case Number 11481595
(index):23 generating case number
(index):24 Current Number: 4
(index):132 CurrentNumber: 4, NewNumber:  true
(index):137 Div tag to update= CaseNumber4
(index):138 Current html content value= 
(index):146 Current Case Number 11481596
(index):23 generating case number
(index):24 Current Number: 5
(index):132 CurrentNumber: 5, NewNumber:  true
(index):137 Div tag to update= CaseNumber5
(index):138 Current html content value= 
(index):146 Current Case Number 11481597
(index):23 generating case number
(index):24 Current Number: 6
```

Thank you for your help!

Julie

Here's my document ready:

```
    var CurrentNumber = 1;
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#getnumber').val("Obtain Case Number");
    $("#Loading").fadeIn("slow");
    /* console logging for debugging -- will be removed */
    console.log("Init...");
    console.log("CurrentNumber: %s", CurrentNumber);
    CheckCurrentCaseNumbers();
    $('#getnumber').on( "click", function() 
        {
            console.log( "generating case number" );
            console.log( "Current Number: %s", CurrentNumber );
            GetNewCaseNumber();
        });
    });
```

The button that fires this:

```
                <form>
                    <input type="button" value="Obtain Case Number" id="getnumber" />
                </form>
```

CurrentNumber needs to be global (I know jQuery doesn't really have globals) so I'm initializing it first thing

Comment: "this is fired by an on click event " show the code with the event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your console output, the html content of the CaseNumber3 element is "11481573" not "", so the IF statement is not able to run.

Look at the highlighted line:

```
(index):19 CurrentNumber: 1 
(index):176 CCCN CurrentCaseNumber: CaseNumber1 
(index):179 CCCN CurrentNumber: 2 
(index):23 generating case number 
(index):24 Current Number: 2 
(index):132 CurrentNumber: 2, NewNumber: true 
(index):137 Current html content value= 
(index):147 Current Case Number 11481573 
(index):23 generating case number 
(index):24 Current Number: 3 
(index):132 CurrentNumber: 3, NewNumber: true 
(index):137 Current html content value= 11481573 // <-- HERE
(index):23 generating case number 
(index):24 Current Number: 3 
(index):132 CurrentNumber: 3, NewNumber: true 
(index):137 Current html content value= 11481573 
(index):23 generating case number 
(index):24 Current Number: 3 
(index):132 CurrentNumber: 3, NewNumber: true 
(index):137 Current html content value= 11481573 
(index):23 generating case number 
(index):24 Current Number: 3 
(index):132 CurrentNumber: 3, NewNumber: true 
(index):137 Current html content value= 11481573 
(index):23 generating case number 
(index):24 Current Number: 3 
(index):132 CurrentNumber: 3, NewNumber: true 
(index):137 Current html content value= 11481573
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. I missed that.   So it looks like my increment is not firing.  I'll look at that.

Comment: moved around the increment and it is working perfectly.  thanks again, it's nice to have another set of eyes sometimes :D